# Как красиво организовать компонент для мультиязычности в Yii2?

Tags: yii2, php

Собственно необходимо реализовать мультиязычность как для интерфейса так и для базы данных. Так-же когда пользователь заходит на сайт необходимо определить язык его браузера и в зависимсоти от этого показывать нужные переводы.

Все это дело я реализовал следующим образом:

**Я создал компонент и добавил его в общую конфигурацию приложения:**

```
'dbTranslator' => [
    'class' => 'common\components\DbTranslator',
    'table' => 'lang'
],
```

**Далее в настройках необходимого мне приложение я вызвал компонент и переопределил язык:**

```
'on beforeRequest' => function ($event) {
    Yii::$app->dbTranslator->init();
    Yii::$app->language = Yii::$app->dbTranslator->getLanguage('code');
},
```

**Весь компонент выглядит вот так:**

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use Yii;

class DbTranslator
{

    /**
     * Таблица где хранятся все доступные языки
     * @param string
     */
    public $table = 'lang';

    /**
     * Все поддерживаемые языки
     * @param array
     */
    private $_supportLanguages;

    /**
     * Язык по умолчанию
     * @param array
     */
    private $_defaultLanguage;

    /**
     * Инициализация компонента
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $languages = (new Query)
                        ->from($this->table)
                        ->orderBy(['default' => SORT_DESC])
                        ->all();

        if (!$languages) {
            throw new InvalidParamException('Languages NOT FOUND');
        }

        if (!isset($languages[0]['default']) || $languages[0]['default'] != 1) {
            throw new InvalidParamException('Default language NOT FOUND');
        }

        $this->_supportLanguages = ArrayHelper::index($languages, 'code');
        $this->_defaultLanguage = $languages[0];
    }

    /**
     * Определение языка на котором будет показан сайт
     * @return array|string
     */
    public function getLanguage($item = false)
    {
        if (Yii::$app->session->get('user.language')) {
            $userLanguage = Yii::$app->session->get('user.language')['code'];
        }
        else if (isset(Yii::$app->request->cookies['language'])) {
            $userLanguage = Yii::$app->request->cookies->getValue('language');
        }
        else {
            $userLanguage = $this->getUserLanguage();
        }

        if (isset($this->_supportLanguages[$userLanguage])) {
            $language = $this->_supportLanguages[$userLanguage];
        } 
        else {
            $language = $this->_defaultLanguage;
        }

        if (!$item || !isset($language[$item])) {
            return $language;
        }

        return $language[$item];
    }

    /**
     * Определение языка браузера пользователя 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserLanguage()
    {
        return substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    }

    /**
     * Язык системы по умолчанию
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultLanguage($item = false)
    {
        if (!$item || !isset($this->_defaultLanguage[$item])) {
            return $this->_defaultLanguage;
        }
        return $this->_defaultLanguage[$item];
    }

    /**
     * Все поддерживаемые языки
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLanguages()
    {
        return $this->_supportLanguages;
    }

    /**
     * Устанавливает выбранный язык
     */
    public function setLanguage($lang)
    {
        if (isset($this->_supportLanguages[$lang])) {
            $language = $this->_supportLanguages[$lang];
        } 
        else {
            $language = $this->_defaultLanguage;
        }

        if (isset(Yii::$app->request->cookies['language'])) {
            Yii::$app->response->cookies->remove('language');
        }        

        Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
            'name'  => 'language',
            'value' => $language['code'],
            'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365, // Запись на 365 дней
        ]));       

        Yii::$app->session->set('user.language', $language);     
    }

}
```

Собственно все работает нареканий нет. Но вот осталось какое-то заднее чувство, что я мог что-то сделать не так.

Поделитесь пожалуйста советами и комментариями к данному подходу.

**Обновление**

А я просто осталю вот это здесь:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/tutorial-i18n.md

Вы меня наверно не поняли. Вся суть компонента определить язык браузера, проверить поддерживается ли он сайтом, если нет то выдать дефолтный и собственно перезаписать `Yii::$app->language`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

аа. тогда вот что:

```
['default' => SORT_DESC]
```

Если default - это название поля, то готовьтесь ловить отказы БД, т.к. это зарезервированное слово и рано или поздно оно попадет в запрос без экранирования

```
substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
```

А что, если этого ключа там нет? А не нужно ли это получать через yii\Request?

```
throw new InvalidParamException('Default language NOT FOUND');
```

У метода нет параметров, зачем кидать сообщение о неверном параметре? зачем писать капсом? текст эксепшена должен позволить энд юзеру быстро раскрутить проблему в обратную сторону.

```
public function getDefaultLanguage($item = false)
{
    if (!$item || !isset($this->defaultLanguage[$item])) {
        return $this->defaultLanguage;
    }
    return $this->defaultLanguage[$item];
}
```

Хотим получить данные по $item, но, если его нет, получаем весь $defaultLanguage. Это крайне неинтуитивно и приведет к сложно раскручиваемым ошибкам на первом пропущенном итеме.

Вообще у класса огромная связность, он тут и запросы определяет, и данные из бд подтягивает, и сами сообщения переводит. Но если уж так, то

```
$language = Yii::$app->session->get('user.language');
```

в случае ненахождения этого параметра в сессии его стоит проставить, все равно класс уже дико связан.

```
/**
 * Все поддерживаемые языки
 * @param array
 */
private $supportLanguages;
```

`@param` - описание аргумента, здесь нужен `@type`. Почти все `@return array` стоит заменить на `@return string[]`, методам стоит проставить `@param`

**Обновление**

[[@NEPSTER 4234223](/users/13983/nepster-4234223)](/users/13983/nepster-4234223), > это скорее для разработчика

Я это и имел в вид под энд юзером. Эксепшен и должен говорить, что база не развернута, а не что что-то не найдено, в текущем варианте нужно лезть в код, чтобы разобраться. Это общая боль всех разрабов, потому что в этот момент надо выйти из локального скоупа и посмотреть со стороны приложения.

> По поводу связанности, все что делает класс, это определяет язык клиента и сверяет его со списком поддерживаемых языков.

Это никак не влияет на вышеописанное, к сожалению. DI там вряд ли нужен, и все равно в Yii его нет.

Comment: Большое спасибо, учту советы, поправлю. 

По поводу экшепшенов, это скорее для разработчика если в базе нет списка языков. 

default используется всегда 1 раз и только в этом компоненте, + активрекорд все такие штуки экранирует. 

По поводу связанности, все что делает класс, это определяет язык клиента и сверяет его со списком поддерживаемых языков. Собственно нет какикого смысле его разделять на кучу маленьких классов, внедряд DI и тп.

Comment: Большое спасибо учел все моменты. 
DI в Yii2 есть. Вот пожалуйста: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/concept-di-container.md

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223, офигеть. Вот сейчас у меня мозг реально поехал. Если у них есть нормальный контейнер, то чего они до сих пор app-то дергают?

Answer (score 0):

Насчет определения языка который больше всего подходит пользователю, можно использовать это: https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls

К тому же этот компонент подставляет язык в URL, что хорошо для CEO.

Для того что бы хранить переводы в БД, достаточно воспользоваться встроенным yii\i18n\DbMessageSource

Подробно о том как сделать мультиязычность можно почитать тут: http://atoumus.github.io/yii2-i18n.html (правда тут сообщения хранятся в PHP файлах а не в БД).